# asp.net treeview swap node text and icon

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Does anyone know if it is possible to swap the order of text and icon for a treeview
in a c#-based asp.net project?

Thanks!

Cheers,

Giuseppe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extender or create your own treeview taking the base as the ASP.Net treeview and override the `Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)` and `RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)` methods.